# MySQL - function which returns execute value

Tags: mysql, sql, execute

I wrote this function:

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION randomDefVal(val varchar(30), tableName varchar(30)) 
    returns varchar(30)

    BEGIN

        SET @query = concat('SELECT ',val,' FROM ',tableName,' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;');
        SET @result = NULL;
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
        return (EXECUTE stmt1);

    END//
```

But I have an error in the last line:

```
SQL Error (1336): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

Which suggests that I cannot write 'return (EXECUTE stmt1);'
How can I return the value, which will be the result of the 'EXECUTE' statement?

Comment: I'm getting this error: **`SQL Error (1336): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger`**

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [SELECT ... INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html).  So you would have something like this within your `BEGIN` and `END` (note that I have not tested this code):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_name VARCHAR(30);
    SET var_name = '';
    SELECT val INTO var_name FROM tableName ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
    RETURN var_name;
END
```